# Replacing Distinct() with GroupBy(...) in Linq

Tags: c#, performance, linq, distinct

To get a performance gain, I am trying to replace the call to `Distinct()` below with `GroupBy(...)`, however I am getting errors.

Any suggestions on how this query should be rewritten to use `GroupBy(...)`?

I am trying to use `GroupBy()` on the `Description` field itself.

```
var result=
         GetResults()
        .Select(x => new SelectList { Text = x.Description, Value = x.Description })
                      .Where(x => x.Text != null)
                      .Distinct()
                      .ToList();
```

---

Comment: I don't think you will get any performance improvement using groupBy

Comment: "I am getting errors" doesn't give us any indication of what you've tried or what the errors are. And do you have any evidence that it will help performance anyway? Next, do you *really* have that query, where you're selecting the description, and then checking that the description property *within the description* is non-null? (So at the top-level you could have `x.Description.Description`) - That seems odd.

Comment: Your linq looks invalid as-is; you're selecting the `Description` field and then filtering on a `Description` property _of that description_.  Also, what makes you think there will be performance gains using a `GroupBy` instead of a `Distinct`?

Comment: Just modified the LINQ...please check now.

Comment: When I run the corresponding SQL query in Database, I am seeing a considerable performance gain using GROUP BY - although there is no difference in the Execution Plan.

Comment: @Sammy - are you certain the SQL is equivalent?  Are you grouping by all columns in the result or just one column?

Comment: @Sammy In your question tags you state you are doing [tag:Linq-to-objects], why are you talking about execution plans? You would only have SQL changes if you where working with Linq2Sql or EntityFramework, not Linq to Objects

Comment: Yes. It returns IQueryable

Comment: @DStanley...I am just grouping by 1 column - Description.

Comment: You might be best off just selecting the descriiption, then distincting and whereing on that and then as the final step create your objects. No need to create objects that you are just going to throw away if they don't match the where or are duplicates. Also if this is going to SQL then SQL is probably going to make more sense of it that way and be more likely to do what you expect in the execution plan. And it seems intuitive to me at least that if you keep the objects small and simpler until you need them to be bigger and more complicated that this would perform better.

Comment: @DStanley...Did you delete your Answer?

Comment: @Sammy Yes because it was wrong - I misread and through you were creating an anonymous type instead of a collection of `SelectList` objects.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your time and assistance. It worked now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't force the Entity Framework to use `GroupBy` instead of `Distinct` clause in generated SQL. Entity framework will determine the appropriate query and it will use that.

One thing that is apparent from your code is that you are only interested in `List<string>` based on *unique* Description values. I don't think you have to create a collection of `SelectList`.

You can do:

```
var result= GetResults()
             .Where(x => x.Description != null)
             .GroupBy(x => x.Description) 
             .Select(grp => grp.Key)
             .ToList();
```

OR

```
var result= GetResults()
             .Where(x => x.Description != null)
             .Select(x => x.Description)
             .Distinct()
             .ToList();
```

Both of the above queries would produce a list of unique description values. Now what type of SQL will be generated against both of these depends on the Entity Framework.

---

Old Answer:

Use `GroupBy` to group on `Description` and then `Select` where Key is not null like:

```
var result= GetResults()
             .Select(x => new SelectList { Text = x.Description, Value = x.Description })
             .Where(x => x.Text != null)
             .GroupBy(x => x.Value) //Here select Value for Description
             .Select(grp => grp.Key)
             .ToList();
```

This will not give you any performance gain, even if there is any, it would be negligible.

Comment: Thank You. Can you please look at the LINQ I mentioned just now in the description & suggest.

Comment: @Sammy, modified my answer based on your edited code.

Comment: Thanks @Habib for your response. I have another question regarding the LINQ. Can you please review my question again?

Comment: Yoour LINQ looks correct. But when executed against the DB, Entity Framework converts it into DISTINCT again. I want to get rid of Distinct n add Group BY.

Comment: @Sammy, I am not sure if you can force that, Entity framework will consider the appropriate query and generate a SQL query based on the LINQ expression. Initially, you didn't have that detailed in the question, so now the answer looks unrelated. Also Is there any particular reason that you are creating a collection of `SelectList` ? Can't you apply your Filter, then Group by and then `ToList` and later convert your `List<string>` to `List<SelectList>` in memory ?

Comment: My apologies for missing out the details while posting the question.

Comment: @Habib...Are you indicating to change the sequence of operators in the LINQ?

Answer (score 0):

You can yry grouping by `Description`:

```
var result=GetResults()
          .GroupBy(x => x.Description)
          .Where(g => g.Key != null)
          .Select(g => new SelectList { Text = g.Key, Value = g.Key })
          .ToList();
```

But I'd be surprised if you got better performance that a `Distinct`.

Comment: Would it not be better to do the where and the groupby/distinct before creating the SelectList objects? Just so that you don't create a bunch just to throw them away... Not that it will make a huge difference, I am sure but its a good habit for when your object creation is a more significant amount of work.

Comment: @Chris...Is this a best practice for LINQ? I am really interested to know more about it. If you have any artifacts or URL, please let me know.